# Jenkins wall display 404

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have the Jenkins Wall display plugin enabled but when I click the link I get a 404. The icon itself is also not found.

The link to view the wall display is like this:

http://ci.mysite.com//plugin/jenkinswalldisplay/walldisplay.html?viewName=All&jenkinsUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fci.mysite.com%2F

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: Any error messages in the Jenkins log ?

Comment: You should check the log files for jenkins and the application server it is running on.  If you also are using a proxy forwarding of some kind you may find answers there as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are two plugins named "Wall Display Plugin" in the list of available plugins in my Jenkins installation (1.473).

I got exactly the same problem as you when installing the one with version `0.6.2`, but version `0.6.15` works. Version 0.6.2 is not mentioned on the plugin page on [Wall Display Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Wall+Display+Plugin).